# Como reemplazar un set de datos grande de un DF por datos de otro DF

Tags: r, dataframe

Estoy con una duda avanzada y espero que me puedan ayudar a resolverla:

Tengo un set de datos con direcciones que vienen incluidas dentro del DF en las columnas "direccion" y "numero", mientras que algunas vienen con la información separada y lista, hay otros  144 casos de los 340 del DF que vienen con la columna "numero" con valores NA.

[image: Columna con datos NA]

Para estos casos, en otros RMD tengo una función que me separa la numeración de la dirección y me genera una nueva columna con estos datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por lo tanto, extraje todos los casos con numeración NA, apliqué la formula y pude separar la información en dos columnas a las que luego renombré como "direccion" y "numero".

Este es el código:

```
aux <- mediafull %>% group_by(direccion) %>% filter(is.na(numero))

aux2 <- aux %>% mutate(direccion = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", direccion)) %>% 
separate(direccion, 
       into = c("nom", "nom2","nom3"), 
       sep = "\\d+", remove = FALSE) %>% 
transmute(nombre, direccion, nom) %>% 
separate(direccion, 
       into = c("num1", "num","num2"), 
       sep = "\\D+", remove = FALSE) %>% 
transmute(nombre, nom, num, num2) %>% 
mutate(across(where(is.character), str_squish)) %>% 
mutate(across(where(is.character), str_trim))

aux2 <- aux2[,c(2:5)]

aux2 <- aux2 %>% rename(direccion = "nom",
                    numero = "num",
                    numero2, "num2")
```

Mi pregunta es como reemplazar los datos en el dataframe original con los nuevos datos que generé en el otro DF.

También indicarles que la nueva DF aux2, solamente tiene las columnas de nombre, direccion, numero y numero2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo atento, les muestro imagenes y el código que estoy usando.

Comment: Bienvenido Alonso Fernandez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se podría solucionar con un *join* entre ambos data frames. Existen varios tipos de joins, pero `left_join()` servirá para tu propósito (porque quieres mantener toda la información del df original *salvo* algunas columnas).

Usando `left_join()` del paquete *dplyr* podrías unir los datos de *aux2* al data frame original utilizando una variable en común (por lo que veo, cada nombre tiene una calle única, por lo que `nombre` serviría como identificador), por ejemplo de la siguiente manera: `mediafull %>% left_join(aux2, by = "nombre)`.

El join generará duplicados de columnas (por ejemplo, te devolverá `direccion.x` y `direccion.y` al haber una variable con el mismo nombre en ambos), pero sólo tendrías que eliminar la copia de la columna que no quieres y renombrar la columna restante. Espero haber sido de ayuda.